# Unable to load dataset from HuggingFace package

Tags: python, dataset, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to load the `AMI` dataset from the [HuggingFace dataset package](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/quickstart.html)

```
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric
dataset = load_dataset('ami','headset-single')
```

However, I am receiving the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Couldn't find file locally at ami/ami.py, or remotely at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/1.8.0/datasets/ami/ami.py.
The file was picked from the master branch on github instead at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/master/datasets/ami/ami.py.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-119884e81101> in <module>()
      1 from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric
----> 2 dataset = load_dataset('ami','headset-single')

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/tasks/__init__.py in task_template_from_dict(task_template_dict)
     25         return None
     26     template = NAME2TEMPLATE.get(task_name)
---> 27     return template.from_dict(task_template_dict)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_dict'
```

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of datasets (1.12.1)? For me the posted code snippets starts downloading data, which I am assuming is intended behavior. Or does this error appear after the initial download?

Comment: Try installing the dataset using the following command: pip install datasets . 
official source: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/installation.html#pip